# implementing dummy program with semaphores in C

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm practising with semaphores in C. I wrote a silly program trying to replicate an example from my class notes. When compiling the following piece of code (gcc -o ex3 ex3.c -lpthread) and executing it (./ex3), nothing happens.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t S1;
sem_t S2;
sem_t S3;

int main(){

    int fa=4;
    int fb=2;
    int sum=0;

    sem_init(&S1, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&S2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&S3, 0, 0);

    /* Proceso A*/
    while (fa<4)
    {
        sem_wait(&S1);
        sum = sum + 2;
        sem_post(&S2);
        fa++;
    }

    /* Proceso B*/
    while (fb<2)
    {
        sem_wait(&S2);
        sem_wait(&S2);
        sum = sum + 3;
        sem_post(&S3);
        fb++;
    }

    /* Proceso C*/
    while (1)
    { /* Imprimir */
        sem_wait(&S3);
        printf("%d,", sum);
        sem_post(&S1);
        sem_post(&S1);
        if (fa>4 && fb>2)
            exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My idea is to play adding waits and signals to Process A and B in order to understand a bit better what these semaphores do. But before, I need to see the result :D

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is to play adding waits and signals to Process A and B in order to understand a bit better what these semaphores do. But before, I need to see the result :D

There is only one process in your small program, so it's really hard to understand semaphores doing this exercise.

Indeed, it always skips the first and the second while loop because of false expression and then it is stuck on

```
sem_wait(&S3);
```

since it is initialized to 0 and never changes. So it will wait forever at this point.

I suggest initializing

```
int fa=0;
int fb=0;
```

so that it will do the stuff inside the first two loops. Also to have an ability to exit from the final while(1) loop we need to increment fa and fb each time after checking while-expression instead of fa++/fb++ at the end of the loop. So the final program will look like:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t S1;
sem_t S2;
sem_t S3;

int main() {

    int fa = 0;
    int fb = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    sem_init(&S1, 0, 4);
    sem_init(&S2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&S3, 0, 0);

    /* Proceso A*/
    while (fa++ < 4) {
        sem_wait(&S1);
        sum = sum + 2;
        sem_post(&S2);
    }

    /* Proceso B*/
    while (fb++ < 2) {
        sem_wait(&S2);
        sem_wait(&S2);
        sum = sum + 3;
        sem_post(&S3);
    }

    /* Proceso C*/
    while (1) { /* Imprimir */
        sem_wait(&S3);
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        sem_post(&S1);
        sem_post(&S1);
        if (fa > 4 && fb > 2)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also I changed exit(0) call to break and added \n to printf instead of comma since it exits after the first iteration.

This will print out 14, then exit. Hope this helps with the result. But to understand semaphores better I suggest starting from something like https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/SEMA/basics.html